# Under what circumstances would glGenBuffers/glGenBuffersARB fail?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl, ogre3d

I am using the Ogre3d engine supporting OpenGL mode.

I have an object called `Chunk` which creates an `Ogre::ManualObject`. Because the creation of the `ManualObject` takes a bit of time I put the task onto a new thread.

Unfortunately, after threading the creation of the `ManualObject` I am now getting the following OgreException:

> "Cannot create GL vertex buffer in GLHardwareVertexBuffer::GLHardwareVertexBuffer"

I looked into the code and it is failing [at this stage](https://github.com/blackberry/OGRE/blob/master/src/RenderSystems/GL/src/OgreGLHardwareVertexBuffer.cpp):

```
glGenBuffersARB( 1, &mBufferId );

if (!mBufferId)
{
    OGRE_EXCEPT(Exception::ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR,
        "Cannot create GL vertex buffer",
        "GLHardwareVertexBuffer::
}
```

This suggests that glGenBuffersARB() is not properly populating mBufferId.

I can't figure out what is causing this, any suggestions?

Comment: What does `glGetError()` tell you before and after the call to `glGenBuffersARB()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Because the creation of the ManualObject takes a bit of time **I put the task onto a new thread.**

That's your problem right there. An OpenGL context can be active in only one thread at a time. If you call OpenGL commands from a thread which doesn't have an OpenGL context bound, all you get are errors.

Comment: Ah thank you! So from this it seems that the best course of action is to have one thread dedicated to graphical tasks. 

What's the proper way to specify which thread should bind the OpenGL context through Ogre?

Comment: @RazorStorm: Sorry I never used the Ogre engine, so I'd have to dig through documentation first, too.

Comment: Ok, no problem! I'll look into the documentation/source and see if I can find something.